# Elastic search words count

Tags: elasticsearch

My Sample elastic index Document,

```
{ "_index": "testdata", "_type": "tweet", "_id": > "Dbo5qmMBSUBLqBARJmBG", "_version": 1, "_score": 1, "_source": { > "fileName": "alibaba.pdf", "chapter": "chapter1", "page": 1, > "timeDate": "2018-05-24T11:06:48+00:00", "text": "So why do we > need machine learning, why do we want a machine to learn as a human? > There are many problems involving huge datasets, or complex > calculations for instance, where it makes sense to let computers do > all the work. In general, of course, computers and robots dont get > tired, dont have to sleep, and may be cheaper. There is also an > emerging school of thought called active learning or > human-in-the-loop, which advocates combining the efforts of machine > learners and humans. The idea is that there are routine boring tasks > more suitable for computers, and creative tasks more suitable for > humans.According to this philosophy, machines are able to learn, by > following rules or algorithms designed by humans and to do repetitive
 and logic tasks desired by a human" } }
```

So How I count words like .. `machine = 3` , `humans =2` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run an aggregation query. It would be something like this :

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "text_aggregation" : {
            "terms" : { 
                "field" : "text" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would work on the whole index. Incase you want to run it on a specific document, you can use something like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "eventCodes":"ET00075293"
        }   
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "text_aggregation" : {
            "terms" : { 
                "fileName" : "alibaba.pdf" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```